# perl getstore gives error 500 . but can downlaod via wget or web browser

Tags: perl

i am trying to download a image from remote server and i get error 500 when i do it via perl getstore. i need to use  getstore. it works for other host but this  provider.

```
use LWP::Simple;   
my $url      = "http://shop.xeptor.co.uk/imgs/cef4cbbe-d86e-420e-aec6-4371d7e9b2bc/250/250/2262497R4xtrep.jpg";
my $filename = "test.jpg";
my $rc = getstore($url, $filename);
if (is_error($rc)) {
  die "getstore of <$url> failed with $rc";
}
```

i can download the image  via  wget or via the web browser and not via  getstore .

Comment: Works for me, including the redirect to https. I suspect you don't have the optional https support. Please check with `perl -mLWP::Protocol::https -E'say LWP::Protocol::https->VERSION'`

Comment: after reading this page. http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/07/now-you-need-lwpprotocolhttps.html

i updated Mozilla::CA and it works.. thanks to everyone for help

Answer (score 1):

The actual URL for that image starts with `https://`. When you request it on `http://`, the browser (or LWP::UserAgent) automatically redirects to the secure version of the URL.

It's not particularly easy to find, but there's a [README.SSL](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.33/README.SSL) file that comes with LWP which explains how to add SSL support to your LWP installation.

Basically, you just need to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https). Everything will then work.

Comment: hi. i have checked and the module   LWP::Protocol::https
 is installed.
   /usr/local/share/man/man3/LWP::Protocol::https.3pm
   /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/https.pm

Comment: After installed LWP::Protocol::https, it works well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your program to use [LWP::UserAgent#mirror](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#mirror) instead, you will get proper [error reporting](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Response), not just a vague status code.

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->mirror(
    'http://shop.xeptor.co.uk/imgs/cef4cbbe-d86e-420e-aec6-4371d7e9b2bc/250/250/2262497R4xtrep.jpg',
    'test.jpg',
);
if ($res->is_error) {
    printf(
        "mirror failed.\nStatus: %s\nContent:\n%s\n\nFull response:\n%s\n",
        $res->status_line,
        $res->content,
        $res->as_string
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks.. now i get a proper error report ..
LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed